# Problems with \EndIf and \EndFor

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

I'm using the algpseudocode package and I want to write a pseudocode. This is my code

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, times, amsmath, colortbl, psfrag}
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, english, boxed, linesnumbered, lined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
...
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Buscar elemento en una lista}
    \KwData{$lista[1,...,x_n]$: lista en la que se va a buscar, $elem$: elemento que se va a buscar}
    \KwResult{$encontrado$: booleano que indica si se encontr\'o el elemento}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{Buscar}{$lista$, $elem$}
            \State $encontrado \gets False$
            \For{i}{1}{n}
                \If{$lista[i]=elem$}
                    \State $encontrado \gets True$
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
            \Return $encontrado$
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
...
\end{document}
```

but I get the following errors when I try to compile it

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               \ALG@b@2@EndIf@0 
l.113           \EndIf
?

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               \ALG@b@2@EndFor@0 
l.114           \EndFor
?
```

Does anyone know how can I compile it?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using incompatible commands from the packages `algorithm2e` and `algpseudocode`; you can use only `algpseudocode` and replace `\KwData`, `\KwResult` with `\Require`, `\Ensure`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}  


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Buscar elemento en una lista}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require $lista[1,...,x_n]$: lista en la que se va a buscar, $elem$: elemento que se va a buscar
\Ensure $encontrado$: booleano que indica si se encontr\'o el elemento
        \Procedure{Buscar}{$lista$, $elem$}
            \State $encontrado \gets False$
            \For{i}{1}{n}
                \If{$lista[i]=elem$}
                    \State $encontrado \gets True$
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
            \Return $encontrado$
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice, however, that the [`IEEEtran HowTo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) document recommends *not* to use `algorithm` from the `algorithm` package:

> **B. Algorithms**
>
> IEEE publications use the `figure` environment to contain algorithms
>   that are not to be a part of the main text flow. Peter Williams’ and
>   Rogerio Brito’s `algorithmic.sty` package [24] or Szász János’
>   `algorithmicx.sty` package [25] (the latter is designed to be more
>   customizable than the former) may be of help in producing
>   algorithm-like structures (although authors are of course free to use
>   whatever LaTeX commands they are most comfortable with in this
>   regard). However, do *not* use the floating `algorithm` environment of
>   `algorithm.sty` (also by Williams and Brito) or `algorithm2e.sty` (by
>   Christophe Fiorio) as the only floating structures IEEE uses are
>   figures and tables. Furthermore, IEEEtran will not be in control of
>   the (non-IEEE) caption style produced by the `algorithm.sty` or
>   `algorithm2e.sty` float environments.

In this case, as recommended by the class, you can enclose your algorithm inside a `figure` environment:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}  

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Pseudocódigo para el algoritmo que busca un elemento en una lista}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require $lista[1,...,x_n]$: lista en la que se va a buscar, $elem$: elemento que se va a buscar
\Ensure $encontrado$: booleano que indica si se encontr\'o el elemento
        \Procedure{Buscar}{$lista$, $elem$}
            \State $encontrado \gets False$
            \For{i}{1}{n}
                \If{$lista[i]=elem$}
                    \State $encontrado \gets True$
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
            \Return $encontrado$
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]